# Typescript interface method Vs abstract method syntax difference

Tags: typescript

unable to understand why the syntax is different for method declaration in an interface and abstract method in an abstract class

```
 interface Moveable {
      start: () => void;
      stop: () => void; // why it is not declared as stop(): void;
  }

  abstract class Vehicle implements Moveable {
      start(): void {
          console.log('Vehicle is moving');
      }
      stop(): void {
          console.log('Vehicle stopped');
      }
      abstract getModal(): void; // why it can not be not defined as getModal: () => void; as it is done for interface
  }

  class Car extends Vehicle {
      getModal() {
          console.log('get modal');
      }
      private test(): void {
          console.log("The car is being tested...");
      }
  }
```

Comment: What is the error you get exactly? 
Because I just tried and I can.

Comment: For interface/abstract member there's no difference between `stop: () => void;` and `stop(): void;`

Comment: on changing  abstract getModal(): void; 
to abstract getModal: () => void; in abstract class 'Vehicle'

I am getting this error 


"class 'Vehicle' defines instance member property 'getModal' but extended class 'car' denies it as instance member function."

Comment: So what the question is? :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between the two syntaxes.  `start: () => void;` declares a field that happens to be a function.  `start(): void;` declares a method. When you use them there is no visible difference between the two, there are however differences between what can be done with them.

An interface field that is a function can be implemented by a class method, but you can use either declaration type in the interface, this would have achieved the same effect:

```
interface Moveable {
    start():void;
    stop(): void; 
}
```

While you can declare an abstract field in the abstract class it has to also be implemented by a field it can't be implemented by a method:

```
class CarNok extends Vehicle {
    getModal() { } // Error, Class 'Vehicle' defines instance member property 'getModal', but extended class 'CarNok' defines it as instance member function
}

class CarOk extends Vehicle {
    getModal: () => { }
}
```

With regard to the difference between fields of type function and methods, you should keep in mind that methods end up on the prototype, while fields end up on the instance, so there is a performance penalty in terms of memory allocations (for simple scenarios it should not be a problem but if you create a lot of instances you might run into troubles). Also there are differences in terms of what happens with `this`:

```
class Car {
    test = 'Car'
    method(){ 
        console.log(this.test); // this is typed as Car but depends on the caller to be passed in corectly (see usage)
    }
    // Useful when we pass fieldWithArrow to event handlers and we want this to be bound to the instance
    fieldWithArrow = () => { 
        console.log(this.test); // this is typed as Car and will be bound to the current instance (thenically it is captured in the constructor when the value is assigned)
    }
    fieldWithFunction = function () { 
        console.log(this.test); // this is typed as any, since this function is just fucntion not a member of Car (might even give a compielr error depending on your settings)
    }
}

let cc = new Car();
cc.method(); // Will output 'Car'
cc.method.apply({ test: 'Not a car'}) // Will output 'Not a car' since we can pass in an arbitrary this to method
cc.fieldWithArrow() // Will output 'Car'
cc.fieldWithArrow.apply({test : 'Not a car'}) // Will output 'Car', this is bound to the function no matter what we pass to apply

cc.fieldWithFunction(); // Will output 'Car', the  function is not declared as a member but is called on the instance of Car
cc.fieldWithFunction.apply({ test: 'Not a car'}) // Will output 'Not a car' since we can pass in an arbitrary this to method
```

Comment: Why field cannot be abstract?

Comment: @AlekseyL. this is the proposal for abstract fields/methods there is no support for abstract fields https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6

Comment: Yeah, but it is supported today

Comment: @AlekseyL. If I were to speculate why, i think they are of limited value, what would a static field mean ? If you don't initialize it there is no emited code for it, an abstract field might force you to initialize it but that does not add much value. No abstract fields in C# or java either.

Comment: c# is another story - you can't put fields in interfaces. But in typescript it is perfectly valid, as well as abstract fields in class

Comment: while I was satisfied by the answer but after reading further comments I checked for abstract field and I was able to declare a abstract field

but got some hint as the error was "Class 'Vehicle' defines instance member property 'getModal', but extended class 'Car' defines it as instance member function." 

so in my example when I declared it as a abstract field by writing 
abstract getModel: () => void; and the in subclass defined it as a method the error occurred.
thanks for the above comments/ discussion

Comment: now when getModel is defined as abstract field, how can I defined it in sub class

interface Moveable {
    start:() => void;
    stop:() => void;
}

abstract class Vehicle implements Moveable {
    start(): void {
        console.log('Vehicle is moving');
    }
    stop(): void {
        console.log('Vehicle stopped');
    }
    abstract getModal:() => void;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    private test(): void {
        console.log("The car is being tested...");
    }
}

Comment: @NishantBaranwal Sorry, I was unable to write back for a while, I wanted to do more research on the topic, I will update the answer shortly

Comment: @NishantBaranwal I was wrong about fields not being abstract , they can be declared as such, I corrected the answer to refrect this, and I added more info about the difference between a field of function type and methods